# Python+Django social network open source projects

Tags: python, django, project, social-networking

I'm looking for some open source, free to change and use project written on Pyton+Django with following features:

- Blog (for site, not for users)
- Users Registration
- User Profiles
- Adding friends, watching what friends added
- Award system for active users (carma, rating)
- Content rating
- Comments
- Probably different users levels (for automatic moderation)

Basically all features of modern social network :) Just want to find some foundation to build site on top of it.

Answer (score 10):

Django has [authentication](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) and [commenting](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/) built in, but most of the rest is covered by [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/).

Comment: I know this is old, but the commenting framework has been removed from django and placed in an external project [here](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments)

Answer (score 3):

There is an application that covers all of your requirements: [vikuit](http://www.vikuit.com).

django, python, social network, profiles, rating, registration....

It's open source, so you can adapt or improve. I used their forums and SSO as a base for another app.